# Writing your Own Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile but it is showing 
`Make: Don't know how to make cc.  Stop.`

what I am doing is this :-
**Hello.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int print();
int main(){
 print();
 return 0;
}
```

**print.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int print(){
 printf("hello\n");
 return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all: OUT
OUT: cc Hello.o print.o -o OUT
Hello.o: Hello.c\
         cc -c Hello.c
print.o: print.c \
         cc -c print.c
clean:  rm -f *.o
clobber: rm -f OUT
```

when I am writing make
$>make
Make: Don't know how to make cc.  Stop.

$>make clean
Make: Don't know how to make rm.  Stop.

what thing I am missing..

I am newbie with this make and makefile, so please suggest me some good tutorials on this

I changed to this :-

```
all: OUT

OUT:; @cc Hello.o print.o  -o OUT

Hello.o:; @cc -c Hello.c

print.o:; @cc -c print.c

clean:; @rm -f *.o

clobber:; @rm -f OUT
```

showing error:-

`cc: warning 1913:`Hello.o' does not exist or cannot be read
cc: warning 1913: `print.o' does not exist or cannot be read
ld: I/O error, file "Hello.o": No such file or directory
Fatal error.
*** Error exit code 1`

Comment: Did you try searching the web for "makefile tutorial"?

Comment: If you try to use `Hello.o` to build `OUT`, then you must tell `Make` that `Hello.o` is a dependency.  Change the line to: `OUT: Hello.o print.o; @cc ...`.  But use `\n\t` instead of `;` as a separator!  Conventions are good and should be flaunted only when necessary and well understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules must be on a different line than the targets, indented with a hard tab:

```
all: OUT
OUT: Hello.o print.o
        cc Hello.o print.o -o OUT
Hello.o: Hello.c
        cc -c Hello.c
print.o: print.c
        cc -c print.c
clean:  
        rm -f *.o
clobber:
        rm -f OUT
```

But this can be simplified by relying on implicit rules and generalized by using some variables:

```
all: OUT
OUT: Hello.o print.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
clean:
        rm -f *.o
clobber:
        rm -f OUT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but showing `Make: Must be a separator on rules line 4.  Stop.` when I am trying your first solution

Comment: You must use tabs as indentation.  If you use spaces, you will get an error very similar to what you are getting.

Comment: now showing:- `cc: warning 1913: `Hello.o' does not exist or cannot be read
cc: warning 1913: `print.o' does not exist or cannot be read
ld: I/O error, file "Hello.o": No such file or directory
Fatal error.`